# Why does mDNS and UPnP (DLNA) behave like this on my iPhone 8-created Access Point?

Tags: networking, bridge, dlna, upnp, mdns

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the network of my iPhone 8's *internet sharing* access point (created when enabling its internet sharing).

In practice the iPhone 8 acts as an AP, default gateway, DHCP, and DNS server. I connect two test devices to it, resulting in a simple topology as I imagine it:

- Some internal bridge (?) (172.20.10.0/28)

  - Some virtual internal interface (?)

    - iPhone 8 (172.20.10.1)
  - iPhone 8 internet sharing AP

    - Test device 1 (iPhone 6)
    - Test device 2 (Macbook Air - "mba.local")

These are the behaviors I observe on this test setup, which leads me to asking:

- When resolving mDNS names ("mba.local") **between the two test devices** it works instantaneously. Tested using the Termius SSH client app for iOS.
- When resolving "mba.local" **on the iPhone 8** it takes over a minute (~80 seconds) to resolve the hostname into an IP. Eventually it *does* work, but super slowly.
- My test device (iPhone 6) connects to "mba.local" using **IPv6**. The iPhone 8 connects using **IPv4**. Confirmed with `who` on the Macbook.
- **UPnP discovery works** between the two test devices (iPhone 6 ↔︎ Macbook Air).
- UPnP discovery **doesn't seem to work** at all on the iPhone 8 when trying to discover the same server (once again using the same app on both iPhone 6 and 8 for testing, albeit not "Termius" this time but the DLNA/UPnP app "TV Assist").

Now, networking isn't my forte, so I'm wondering if there are **any apparent explanations for this behavior?** Different facets of this question include:

- Why is mDNS resolution so incredibly slow in this one case?
- Why does UPnP only work between test devices?
- Does the detail about IPv4 vs. IPv6 suggest anything?
- Is it suggestive that, between the iPhone 8 and the test device, mDNS kind of works, while UPnP doesn't seem to work at all?

I know there might not be any *definite* answer considering the closed nature of the device, but I'm asking if there is a reasonable and likely explanation that jumps out based on what can be observed here.

As I understand it both mDNS and UPnP rely on multicast, so the behavior would have been easier to understand if neither worked, but I don't think I know enough about the subject yet to think about it clearly.